# Jquery .load can't load li

Tags: jquery

I have this code and the image does not load to the selected div

```
base = "www.samplee/someimage.jpg";
var img = "<img src='"+base+"' />";

imgpreview.load(ul,function(){
            loader.text('mana');
            console.log(imgfield);
});
```

what's wrong with my code?

Comment: dude, both first lines are not existing in the code below. Do you expect any conjure?

Comment: Not only that, but he has a `ul` defined in load, and yet he's saying that they don't load to the selected `div` lol

Answer (score 0):

Well, what is `imgpreview`?  It's not defined.  Try this instead:

`img.load("/ ul", function() { // Your code in here... });`

If you need it to load into a `div` element, than is that what `imgpreview` is supposed to represent?  The div element?  If so, is that the class or the id of the `div` element?